# Split and Mask does not work at localhost

Tags: gwt

Gwt Version 2.2
I want to split my string and set mask for a textitem

For Exampe:

```
String b=ADN.CNNC.RR.44;
String[] a= b.split("\\.");

textItem.setMask(a[0] + ">C<CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC");
textItem.setValue(a[a.length -1]);

textItem's Mask : ADN
textItem's Value : 44
```

Not problem at development mode it works but at localhost split does not work it shows me

`textItem's Value :ADN.CNNC.RR.44`

any answer?

Answer (score 0):

[JRE emulation reference](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_lang) doesn't mention the String.mask() method, I guess it's not supported then.